# What type of ceiling is this and how can I mount a hook to it?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, mounting, anchor

I’m trying to mount a ceiling hook above a table (to hang a lamp) but can’t drill more than about a quarter inch into the ceiling. To try and figure out what kind of ceiling I have, I removed one of the ceiling-mounted LED light fixtures:

[image: Light fixture]

Is this a concrete ceiling? Is it possible to mount a hook in it? For reference, I live in a 60s era apartment building.

Comment: If concrete will need masonry drill bit and probably a hammer drill.  Usually the cement is easy to drill in, but you will always find stones in the way that make drilling hard.  Edit in the weight of the light so someone can recommend the proper anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be concrete. Concrete ceilings/floors are common and typical in some apartment buildings, particularly (but not limited to) The "high-rise" sort of apartment building.

If the building has a "supervisor" or similar position (person in charge of maintenance, etc.) it would be best to consult with them before whipping out a masonry drill and coming through your upstairs neighbor's floor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ecnerwal. I agree that if it is concrete, I’m inclined not to try to drill through it without more serious investigation.

Comment: Be aware of the possibility of a ‘post tensioned slab’ before you drill. They apparently started doing those in the 50s.